# get user country by ip and show it on top of dropdown list but NOT preselect it

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, geoip

I have a drop-down list in my form which preselect user's country based on his/her IP and it works fine.

**Problem:** This drop-down list question is required field, so if user didn't answer it, he should not be able to go to the next page. My problem is that since it is preselected in the list, even if user didn't selected it, he can go to next page.

**What I need:** I would like to know if it is possible to get users country by their IP, but **NOT preselect** it, and just simply **show it on top of the list** for instance before "Leave Blank" option (so user can see it easily).

This is my code:

```
<label> Where were you born?<span>*</span></label>
<div class="fieldset content">  
<select name="q5[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px">

<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$gi = geoip_open('/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_STANDARD);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$preselect_country = geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, $ip);

include('newCountry.php');

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
    if($preselect_country == $line['country']){
       $selected = "selected";
   }else{
       $selected = "";
    }

 echo "<option value=\"{$line['country']}\" {$selected}>{$line['country']}</option>\n";
  }
    geoip_close($gi);

 ?>
</select>
</div>
```

I appreciate if someone can help me fix it.

Thanks,

Comment: You can leave the first item (the default if nothing else is selected) blank (e.g. `<option>Select one...</option>` -- there is no `value` attribute) and just insert the user's country as the second item in the dropdown menu.

Comment: @ialarmedalien: sorry, but this is my question, I don't know how to insert the user country as second or first option! :( If it was fixed (e.g always Italy) I could, but now I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your `select` to have a blank first value and put the user's country as the second option in the list. The other countries can go below it. To set this up using your PHP script, you can create two strings, one for the top of the list (with the blank option and the user's country), and the other with the rest of the list:

```
$list_top = "<option>Choose one...</option>\n";
$list_bottom = "";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
    if($preselect_country == $line['country']){
        $list_top .= "<option value=\"{$line['country']}\">{$line['country']}</option>\n";
    }else{
        $list_bottom .= "<option value=\"{$line['country']}\">{$line['country']}</option>\n";
    }
}
echo $list_top . $list_bottom;
```